How to install an additional laguage on ubuntu 22.04
Trying to follow this tutorial, but there no such activities menu

How to install an additional keyboard language on Ubuntu 22.04?

That image does not work. If it is test do not show a picture include the steps in the question, if it is not text not good.

I was able to install the dual English/Arabic Apple keyboard on my Ubuntu24 using the user's interface as follows:
Settings > Keyboard > Input Source > + Add Input Source...
Under Settings / Keyboard
It worked just fine as long as I connect by USB cable.

That is not what was asked.
